# Operating system with option to connect to other LAN PCs via RDP

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, operating-system

I have an environment where a number of people connect to their office PCs from home via RDP using port forwarding.

My router has a limitation in that it cannot handle more port forwarding entries therefore I am looking for an OS through which they can connect remotely and on doing so will display a list of PC (including their own PC) to connect to. In this way I would only need one port forwarding rule in my router.

I know I can do this with Windows but would like to ask if there is a simple OS (even Linux) which, when connecting to it via RDP would simply list the PC to connect to - nothing more. I would prefer this rather than a Windows installation so as not to confuse them into thinking that they have connected to their own PC in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more then a solution.

- Setup an RDP Gateway. Every client use it, so you need to configure only ONE port forwarding. To the RDP Gateway. More details here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731150%28v=ws.11%29.aspx
- Use a VPN. This is my favorite. In this case, just one port forwarding, for the VPN. Clients will connect to VPN, and then gain an ip address in the network. I used a Debian Linux to do this, but some router can do the work. In case, take a look to OpenVPN: https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN
- Another solution is to have a linux server, forward to ssh port and use ssh tunnel, but this can be uncomfortable for users.